# <ejb-link> not giving unique EJB in Weblogic 12c - Causing jndi Name collision

Tags: ejb, weblogic-10.x, weblogic12c

I am migrating project from Weblogic 10.3 to Weblogic 12c.I have an MDB which reference another EJB (EJB 2.1) as below.

```
   <ejb-local-ref>
      <ejb-ref-name>ejb/WorkerSBLocalHome</ejb-ref-name>
      <ejb-ref-type>Session</ejb-ref-type>
      <local-home>test.WorkerSBLocalHome</local-home>
      <local>test.WorkerSBLocal</local>
     <ejb-link>WorkerEJB.jar#WorkerSB</ejb-link>
   </ejb-local-ref>
```

Getting below exception

```
   You must set a different JNDI name in the weblogic-ejb-jar.xml deployment descriptor or corresponding annotation for this EJB before it can be deployed.
```

**EDIT :**
The Weblogic's weblogic-ejb-jar.xml has local-jndi-name and it is getting registered in Weblogic JNDI tree

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removal of local-jndi-name from weblogic-ejb-jar.xml and put below for lookup

```
   java:comp/env/ejb
```